# How do I serialize TransactionBuilder

Tags: corda

I need several nodes to build one transaction. To achieve that I create a `TransactionBuilder` and pass it to nodes that then add their states to it.

This seems to be a legit practice since the [official documentation](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.transactions/-transaction-builder/) mentions `[TransactionBuilder] is intended to be passed around contracts that may edit it by adding new states/commands.`

However when running a unit test the network throws this exception:

`Class class net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder is not on the whitelist or annotated with @CordaSerializable.
java.io.NotSerializableException: Class class net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder is not on the whitelist or annotated with @CordaSerializable.`

I tried white-listing `TransactionBuilder`, but the it threw this:

`net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder -> outputs(java.util.List<net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState<net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState>>) -> java.util.List<net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState<net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState>> -> net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState<net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState> -> data(net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState) -> state(com.luxoft.poc.mobi.data.state.TransportAgreement$State) -> Class class com.luxoft.poc.mobi.data.state.TransportAgreement$State is not on the whitelist or annotated with @CordaSerializable.
java.io.NotSerializableException: net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder -> outputs(java.util.List<net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState<net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState>>) -> java.util.List<net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState<net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState>> -> net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState<net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState> -> data(net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState) -> state(com.luxoft.poc.mobi.data.state.TransportAgreement$State) -> Class class com.luxoft.poc.mobi.data.state.TransportAgreement$State is not on the whitelist or annotated with @CordaSerializable.`

What am I doing wrong? How do I work around it?

We use Corda 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message, you also need to add `TransportAgreement.State` to the whitelist, as you are sending it as part of the transaction builder.

Comment: Could you explain why `TransactionBuilder` is not serializeble out-of -the-box? The documentation suggests it should be.

Comment: It's been debated. It's been left as non-serializable because until a signature is applied to the transaction (i.e. when it's still a builder), any counterparties can modify it by adding/removing components. If you aren't careful to check for this when you get the transaction builder back, you can accidentally sign a transaction without realising what it contains.